# Firestore data trigger events in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

Are there anyways to get firestore database trigger callbacks when using Cloud Run?

Currently there are options for getting Audio log events but didn't find a way to get firestore update/create/delete triggers when using Cloud Run. However cloud functions has support though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time I write this, there are no hooks for Firestore change events for Cloud Run that are similar to what you see in Cloud Functions.  This is something that might [change in the future with EventArc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/build-event-driven-applications-in-cloud-run).  It is in "preview" and not generally available yet.  Quoted from that blog:

> With Eventarc, you can address key use cases ... by acting on events
> that originate from Cloud Storage, BigQuery, Firestore and more than
> 60 other Google Cloud sources.

In the meantime, you could instead write a simple [Cloud Function Firestore trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) to receive document change events, and proxy those events to Cloud Run via a pubsub topic or HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I was thinking to fire a message through pub/sub currently but wondering if there is any other option.

Also, 60+ events are through Audit Log events. Do you see those reliable for using as data change events to trigger cloud run instance?

Comment: I'm not aware of other options.

Comment: @DougStevenson they added a lot of cloud firestore events, but no document CREATE, DELETE event (#plamInTheFace)

Comment: Anyone know if this has changed in the last 2 years? @Ayyappa?